# Can a Meteor method call get invoked via Collection.findOne

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor code. Can I define a method "or a function" on the server and call it on `collectionName.findOne({id: 'someId'}).methodName;` on the client?
Being new to Meteor, I don't know if this is possible and if so, what would the syntax look like? Thanks

This code is just a brain dump.

```
//server
Meteor.method({
  doWork1: function (args) {
    //do work
    return something;
  }
});

MyCol = new Mongo.Collection('myCol');
MyCol.insert({item: "envelopes", qty : 100, myFunc: doWork1});

//client
Meteor.call(MyCol.findOne({item: 'envelops'}).myFunc;
```

**Edited**:

Blaze Sahlzen comments made me think and add the following.

The reasons why I thought to give a mongo collection a try is this:

Stage one: the user fills up a form and click a button, the input values need to be used as arguments for a method which when successfully returns, the form gets modified to show different input fields for the user to fill up again and click the SAME button.
Stage two: same as stage one but with different input fields again.
Stage n: same as stage n-1 but with different input fields again.

I need to store all input values and group them by their stage identifier.
Each method may add/remove different kind of input controls for the next stage.

Since the SAME button will be used thus I don't have different buttons for different methods, so I came up with my original question "brain dump code". You are welcome to reinvent or change it and offer yours. :) Thanks again.

**edited 2**
A practical example could look like this:

```
var stageOne = {};
//for each DOM input 
stageOne[inputName][i]= [inputValue][i];

myCol.insert({'stageOne': stageOne});
//then an observer for stageOne
```

But I just can't get my head around how to "link" each stage with the correct method to call without having to use a long if or switch conditional statement.

Comment: Is it necessary to save Meteor method names in a collection?

Comment: Good question thus I edited my question. please see.

Comment: Dynamically changing input elements, handling them and keeping track of them - these are what your question is dealing with if I'm not wrong?

Comment: Yes for the most part. :)

Comment: Interesting idea! I think a practical example needs to be thought of in order to develop this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, if I understand what you mean, I don't think you need observeChanges. The following solution might be a bit extensive, so bear with me.

Firstly you need a session variable to control on the client side which form values need to be shown. You could introduce this variable in your Template.name.onRendered.

```
Session.set('stage',1);
```

Then you have your input fields

```
<form>
    <label id="label1">{{label1}}</label>
    <input id="field1" type="text"/>

    <label id="label1">{{label2}}</label>
    <input id="field2" type="text"/>

    <label id="label1">{{label3}}</label>
    <input id="field3" type="text"/>

    <button id="form-submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I can imagine that you want to switch up the names of their labels to reflect the change in forms as you go to different stages. As a result you can write helpers as such:

```
'label1': function(){
    var myStage = Session.get('stage');
    if (myStage == 1){return '<label-title-for-stage-1>';
    } else if (myStage == 2){return '<label-title-for-stage-2>';}
    } else if .... etc.
}
```

Any changes to the session variable 'stage' will force the helper to reload, making it ideal to update form titles as you go through your stages.

You can then write an event for the button click event as such:

```
'submit #form-submit': function(){
    var options = {
        stage: Session.get('stage'),
        values: [
        { value: $('#field1').val(), name:$("#label1").text() },
        { value: $('#field2').val(), name:$("#label1").text() },
        { value: $('#field3').val(), name:$("#label3").text() }]
    }
    Meteor.call('storeValues', options, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        Session.set('stage',result);
    });
}
```

This will essentially combine the filled fields into one object and call upon a server method, waiting for a callback from the server that tells the client which stage to move to.

Now, on the server side you can insert the values for this particular user in your collection and see if a particular stage has filled up and return whether the client can move on to the next stage.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'storeValues': function(options){
        for (var i = 0; i < options.values.length; i++){
            myCol.insert({
                value:options.values[i].value,
                name:options.values[i].name,
                stage: options.stage
            });
        }
        if (options.values.length > 'amount-per-stage'){
            return options.stage + 1;
        } else {
            return options.stage;
        }
    }
});
```

This way you store the data that gets entered in each form, while moving up one stage each time if all fields have been entered.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use observeChanges:

```
var query = MyCol.find({item: 'envelops'});
var handle = query.observeChanges({
    added: function () {
        somethingHappened();
    },
    changed: function () {
        somethingHappened();
    }
});

var somethingHappened = function(){
    // do something
}
```

Query contains your collection, and the handle function automatically checks whether any changes are being made to that collection, triggering the somethingHappened function if there are.

Inside somethingHappened you can place the behaviour that you would normally place in your method.

You can use observeChanges both client side and server side, but in this case you only need it on the server side.

Comment: I am trying to understand the first line of code, are you supplying a Document as an argument to 'myCol.find' [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) requires otherwise unless the supplied document argument is considered to be the required selector humm

Comment: The first line was incorrect, so I can imagine that it was hard to understand. When correct, the first line returns a part of the myCol collection with 'envelops' as the 'item' parameter, or any changes to that part of the collection over time.

Comment: Please see my **edits**, will I have to write your code snippet for every "stage", a new query and handle for stageOne, an another qury and handle for stageTwo ... stageN?